# Java, getting : java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe when ouput a excel file

Tags: java, sockets, exception, servlets, weblogic

I have an  JEE application with a problem:
Usually A web browser make a request to export data to excel file and the server send the xls file to the web browser client.

Under certain request parameters sent by the  browser making a request to export data to excel file,  the server dont send the response, instead the server always throws java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

The code related is:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream memStream = getDocumentBO().generateDoc(document, numExp, tipo,     indexCol, nameCol, widthCol, orden, sc, url, true);
int size = memStream.size();
Long name = new Date().getTime();
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", ("attachment;filename=" + name + ".xls"));
response.setContentLength(size);
ServletOutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
memStream.writeTo(ouputStream);
ouputStream.flush();
ouputStream.close();
```

The line of code that causes the exception is      **memStream.writeTo(ouputStream);**

the stack trace is:

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunkNoTransfer(ChunkOutput.java:548)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunks(ChunkOutput.java:505)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.flush(ChunkOutput.java:382)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.checkForFlush(ChunkOutput.java:469)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.write(ChunkOutput.java:304)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.write(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:169)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:112)
at net.gencat.acc.sic.action.ExportAction.execute(ExportAction.java:202)
```

the browser client has not been closed between the moment it makes the request and the moment the server throws the exception. the server is weblogic .

I would like to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

> the browser client has not been closed between the moment it makes the request and the moment the server throws the exception.

Oh yes it has. The peer has closed the connection. No two ways about it.